# Reading a string from a file until 0x00 fast

Tags: string, file, rust

I have a binary file that stores strings like chars with a null byte for termination, which I need to read into my program. The strings look something like this:
`74 65 73 74 00` ("test")

This is my current code that reads one string in:

```
let mut pointer = (some_offset);
let mut character: u8;
let mut name: String = "".to_string();
loop{
    character = read::read_u8(&path, pointer as usize);
    pointer += 0x01;
    if character == 0{break;}
    name.push(character as char);
}
```

This is the read_u8 function:

```
pub fn read_u8(filename: &String, offset: usize) -> u8{
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let mut buffer = [0; 1];
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset as u64)).unwrap();
    file.read(&mut buffer[..]).unwrap() as u8;

    return u8::from_be_bytes(buffer);
}
```

Now, this is quite slow. It takes around 6 seconds to read in 500 of these. Is there any way I can speed up either of these two code snippets up?

Comment: For one thing, don't close and re-open the file every time. That's what is killing your performance. It's possible to just open the file once and read one byte at a time.

Comment: Also, to create a new empty string, just use `String::new()`

Comment: Once you've fixed the constantly-opening-and-closing-the-file issue (which will speed it up *massively*), if it's still too slow, consider processing the stream a word at a time (see [GCC's strlen implementation](https://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/strlen.c.html)), or even a 128-bit or 256-bit vector at a time.

Comment: If your input file is not gigantic, you  might consider reading the entire file into a Vec<u8> and then either copy (or simply point to) strings within that buffer.

Comment: Well alright I do instead of passing a reference to the path I'm passing a reference to the, as mutable declared, opened file, however now file.seek() and file.read() tell me that they cannot borrow it as mutable because it isn't declared as.
let mut file = std::fs::File::open(path.clone()).unwrap();   (How I declared it)

Comment: Also you can buffer the read.

Comment: @CorruptMem you have to pass in an `&mut File`, not whatever it is you passed in. There's also no reason to `seek` into the file on each read since `read` automatically increments the "current location" pointer, you only need to seek once when opening the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `read_u8()` function works fine if you're only interested in reading a single byte, but its inefficient for reading multiple bytes since the file shouldn't be closed and reopened and read calls can be buffered.

For reading nul-terminated strings, you should wrap your file in a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) and use [`.read_until()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Seek, SeekFrom};

let filename = "./test.bin";
let offset = 0x0100;

let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
let mut file = BufReader::new(file);
let mut data = Vec::new();
file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset)).unwrap();
file.read_until(b'\0', &mut data).unwrap();

// read_until() will include the trailing '\0' unless
// it encounters EOF, just trim it off if its there.
if data.last() == Some(&0) {
    data.pop();
}

let name = String::from_utf8(data);
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f004532a3d64cdd72686d8ba02d74ef6).

Comment: Works much faster now, Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this answer works please accept it by clicking the checkmark beside the answer.